# Brightness function keys problem

Tags: 13.10, brightness, hp, function-keys

I have an HP 650 notebook, and I just finished installing ubuntu 13.10 . The problem is that brightness function keys don't work ( f2 and f3 ). I tried changing GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and updating grub but it doesn't work.

Directory /sys/class/backlight is empty.

and "lspci | grep -i vga" command outputs the following:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation
>   Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Any help, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

much more later :D
I installed ubuntu 14.04 : Perfect ! Not a single problem !

Comment: I think it's an answer, no ? He answers his own question by saying "I installed 14.04 and the issue is solved". This way, people will see that on HP650, 14.04 solves the problem with brightness.

Comment: That's my point. I kept using windows all this time and now it's all good with 14.04. I just remembered this question and came here to mention it.