# Nvidia Brightness problem Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, brightness

The brightness control in Ubuntu 18.04 does not have any effect on the screen brightness on my Asus TUF A15.  I have tried everything suggested here: [Brightness problem Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034305/brightness-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

I have added to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf as this:

```
Section "OutputClass"
   Identifier "nvidia"
   MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
   Driver "nvidia"
   Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
   ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
   Option "Backlight" "acpi_video0"
EndSection
```

And changed the relevant line in /etc/default/grub to read:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=video"
```

I've run apt update-grub and rebooted.  I've tried nvidia-drivers-330 and 340.  All to no effect.

Anything else I can try?  Is my 10-nvidia.conf file correct?

Comment: Tried with nvidia-driver 450 also for GTX 1650Ti. Still not working. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to kernel 5.9 sorted this problem out, as older kernels are not able to deal with AMD CPUs and Nvidia graphs cards together, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Asus Tuf A15 which has Nvidia GTX 1650 graphics card. I have Ubuntu 20.04(LTS) installed with kernel `5.8.0-36-generic`.

I could'nt fix the original brightness-bar-not-working issue, but managed to find an alternative. Apart from the system file changes mentioned in the question, I used a software called Brightness controller to adjust my screen brightness. [This](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/05/install-brightness-controller-utility-in-ubuntu-16-04-higher/#:%7E:text=Brightness%20Controller%20is%20a%20simple,from%201%25%20to%20100%25!&text=It%20supports%20an%20arbitrary%20number%20of%20displays) articles is a crisp and clear explanation of how to use Brightness controller.

Answer (score 0):

I am **ASUS TUF-17** series user.
and currently installed 20.04 LTS focal-fosa release in it.

So here is my solution for controlling so bright white light on your laptop, hope it'll helped out for other users too-

First of all,

Plzzz, Plzzz, Plzzz didn't do anything for your brightness ,if you have ***ASUS A15,A17 or any ASUS ROG series or gaming laptop***.

I tried all of the possible ways to do so-
Neither changing the

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"

is worked,nor

> any changes in grub file config.

or **You will get stucked into infinity reboot** .

This Nvidia problem is so frustating.

*The simplest way to reduce eye strain is to install **Redshift** App for linux.

**#1) Redshift**

you can, using this command-*

```
sudo apt-get install redshift

sudo apt-get install redshift-gtk

sudo apt update
```

*This app is so beautifully optimises brightness intensity automatically,You just didn't need to control brightness.*

Now, You can use different IDE's with having white background easily in late night hours.

Some More App I personally suggest you for your eye-care is-

**#2**

> Safe Eyes   ____"available in ubuntu store" .......(it'll let you make some breaks in long working hours)

**#3**

> Screen Shader .......(it is a chrome extension for more light filtering)

***That's ALL.
Now, You didn't need to worry about your Brightness***

Comment: This is [the exact same thing you posted to another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434362/brightness-function-keys-problem/1313314#1313314) just a few minutes ago. Please don't spam the website.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 16.04 and explicitly installed nvidia driver on my new laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad P73). I solved my problem by:

1. look in file `/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/actual_brightness` for the value you adjusted with system-settings glider (in my case the value was 73).
2. open a terminal and enter `sudo -i` to establish the sudo environment
3. then enter:

   ```
   cd /var/lib/systemd/backlight
   ```

   and then:  `ls`    to list the files in this directory.
   There should be a file named  `pci-0000:01:00.0:backlight:nvidia_0`
   I'm not sure if that's the standard, but probably the `nvidia_0` ending is.
4. because gedit cannot handle editing pci-xxx-files directly you first have to copy this file to any "standard"-name, I chose pciX.
   so now enter:  `cp pci-0000:01:00.0:backlight:nvidia_0 pciX`
5. now edit pciX, enter: `gedit pciX`
   and change the value in this file from 100 to the value you saw in step 1 above (e.g.73).
   Save and close the file.
6. now copy your changes in the correct file by entering:

   ```
   cp pciX pci-0000:01:00.0:backlight:nvidia_0
   ```

   This overwrites the original `pci-000..etc.`-file
7. restart ubuntu, and the brightness should now be at the adjusted level, i.e. not at 100%!!

Maybe there's a better way with a different editor, and I'm not sure what happens if an nvidia update is installed, but that probably does not happen so often.

Answer (score 0):

For me, in Ubuntu 18.04.6 with `nvidia-driver-495` it only worked to add this kernel option to `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

then execute `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Source: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/brightness-not-working-ubuntu-20-04-lenovo-legion-5-15imh05/178058/17